# Ruby: How to acquire file lock for writing?

Tags: ruby, file, filelock

What I want to achieve is this:

1. if some other process is holding the lock, quit
2. otherwise acquire the lock for writing

The Ruby code I am trying to modify is.

```
File.open(filename, "wb") { |inf|
  if inf.flock(File::LOCK_EX|File::LOCK_NB) == 0
    ...
  end
}
```

The codes I can find are usually using `"rb"`. If I change to `"wb"`, there is a problem: because if some other process is working on the file (which I cannot know until attempting the lock), the file will be wiped out by `File.open(..., "wb")`.

Is there a way? Thanks.

## New Info

I think one way is to use `"File::RDWR|File::CREAT"`, so that you can open file first and it won't wipe out its content, then try the lock. Not sure if there is other way, but `"wb"` probably will not work. I guess this is an awkwardness of Ruby: you have to open file first before acquiring the lock. I think these two steps should be made atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a lock file and lock that instead.  If your `filename` is say "path/to/file.txt" then create a lock on "path/to/file.txt.lock".  Once you've acquired your lock on the lock file, edit the real file as normal.

Comment: Phillip, I am thinking about how to do that without running into timing issues. For example, one would not just confirm  `"path/to/file.txt.lock"` does not exist before creating it in write mode, as the file could be created between the execution of the two operations. One possibility is to use a database to get the lock, as they are built to do that. Is there a safe, easy way to do this with just `IO` methods?

Comment: Open the lock file for writing. Then try to acquire a lock. Doesn't matter how many processes open the lock file. Just that only one of them can acquire an exclusive lock.